# laravel REST api post method

Tags: mysql, rest, laravel, eloquent

im making an api in laravel but when i send from a post request it display nothing it work only when i send the values in the url what im i doing wrong here is my code !

```
$user = new userInscription;

            $user->nom = Request::get('name');
            $user->pseudo = Request::get('pseudo');
            $user->userId = Request::get('userId');
            $user->hasFiat = Request::get('hasFiat');
            $user->optin = Request::get('optin');
            $user->mail = Request::get('mail');

            $pseudo = Input::get('pseudo');
            $userId = Input::get('userId');
            $hasFiat = Input::get('hasFiat');

    if($pseudo == '' || $hasFiat == '' )
        {
            return Response::json( array(
            'status'  => 'ko',
            'message'  => 'missing mandatory parameters')
            );
        }

    else if($userId == '')
        {
            if( $user->save() )
            {
                $id = DB::table('user')
                ->where('pseudo','LIKE',$pseudo)
                ->pluck('userId');

                return Response::json(array(
                    'status'  => 'ok',
                    'message'  => 'success',
                    'userId' => $id
                ));
            }
            else
            {
                return Response::json(array(
                    'message'  => 'error while saving this user !!',   
                ));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you add a post route for this method ?

Comment: no here is my routes 
Route::group(array('prefix' => ''), function()
{
Route::resource('user', 'userInscriptionController');
});

Answer (score 1):

Laravel REST-ful (Resourceful) controlllers has pre-configured routes (can be re-configured):

According to : http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

```
+-----------+---------------------------+---------+------------------+
|   Verb    |           Path            | Action  |    Route Name    |
+-----------+---------------------------+---------+------------------+
| GET       | /resource                 | index   | resource.index   |
| GET       | /resource/create          | create  | resource.create  |
| POST      | /resource                 | store   | resource.store   |
| GET       | /resource/{resource}      | show    | resource.show    |
| GET       | /resource/{resource}/edit | edit    | resource.edit    |
| PUT/PATCH | /resource/{resource}      | update  | resource.update  |
| DELETE    | /resource/{resource}      | destroy | resource.destroy |
+-----------+---------------------------+---------+------------------+
```

Referencing the table each of the Verb must correspond to the action method in the controller.

For example if your Resourceful Route is registered as:

```
Route::resource('user', 'userInscriptionController');
```

Then to POST to `user` resource, you need to have `userInscriptionController@store` action (i.e. method called `store()` in your `userInscriptionController`.

To avoid manually creating each of these actions, you can use Laravel's artisan `controller:make`

```
php artisan controller:make userInscriptionController
```

which will generate all these actions for you, then you just need to fill in your logic to complete the resource.

Answer (score 0):

if request is GET then:

```
if (Request::isMethod('get'))
{
$user = new userInscription;

            $user->nom = Request::get('name');
            $user->pseudo = Request::get('pseudo');
            $user->userId = Request::get('userId');
            $user->hasFiat = Request::get('hasFiat');
            $user->optin = Request::get('optin');
            $user->mail = Request::get('mail');

            $pseudo = Input::get('pseudo');
            $userId = Input::get('userId');
            $hasFiat = Input::get('hasFiat');

    if($pseudo == '' || $hasFiat == '' )
        {
            return Response::json( array(
            'status'  => 'ko',
            'message'  => 'missing mandatory parameters')
            );
        }

    else if($userId == '')
        {
            if( $user->save() )
            {
                $id = DB::table('user')
                ->where('pseudo','LIKE',$pseudo)
                ->pluck('userId');

                return Response::json(array(
                    'status'  => 'ok',
                    'message'  => 'success',
                    'userId' => $id
                ));
            }
            else
            {
                return Response::json(array(
                    'message'  => 'error while saving this user !!',   
                ));
            }
        }

}
```

===================
if request is POST then:

```
if (Request::isMethod('post'))
{
$user = new userInscription;

            $user->nom = Request::post('name');
            $user->pseudo = Request::post('pseudo');
            $user->userId = Request::post('userId');
            $user->hasFiat = Request::post('hasFiat');
            $user->optin = Request::post('optin');
            $user->mail = Request::post('mail');

            $pseudo = Input::post('pseudo');
            $userId = Input::post('userId');
            $hasFiat = Input::post('hasFiat');

    if($pseudo == '' || $hasFiat == '' )
        {
            return Response::json( array(
            'status'  => 'ko',
            'message'  => 'missing mandatory parameters')
            );
        }

    else if($userId == '')
        {
            if( $user->save() )
            {
                $id = DB::table('user')
                ->where('pseudo','LIKE',$pseudo)
                ->pluck('userId');

                return Response::json(array(
                    'status'  => 'ok',
                    'message'  => 'success',
                    'userId' => $id
                ));
            }
            else
            {
                return Response::json(array(
                    'message'  => 'error while saving this user !!',   
                ));
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: it's the same nothing is appearing when i use post !!

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, you are using

```
Route::resource('user', 'userInscriptionController');
```

which will generate following routes

```
Verb        |   Path                    | Action        | Route Name
------------------------------------------------------------------------
GET         | /resource                 | index         | resource.index
GET         | /resource/create          | create        | resource.create
POST        | /resource                 | store         | resource.store
GET         | /resource/{resource}      | show          | resource.show
GET         | /resource/{resource}/edit | edit          | resource.edit
PUT/PATCH   | /resource/{resource}      | update        | resource.update
DELETE      | /resource/{resource}      | destroy       | resource.destroy
```

And as you can see, the only action allowing `post` is `store`. So you should use this one or add `post` route for an other method like this :

```
Route::post('your_url', array('as' => 'your_route_name', 'uses' => 'YourController@yourMethod'));
```

I hope it's clear now